# How to open procedure body if I connected using linux putty terminal of Oracle database server

Tags: linux, oracle, putty

Not able to see complete stored procedure body using putty.
Please tell me command.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want us to guess what you currently do to view procedure body (and fail to do so)?

OK, so let us guess. My attempt: if you use SQL*Plus, `set long`:

```
SQL> set long 10000
SQL> select text from user_source where name = 'F_TEST';

TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
function f_test (par_country in varchar2)
  return sys_refcursor
is
  l_filter_value dict.filter_value%type;
  l_rc           sys_refcursor;
begin
  select filter_value
    into l_filter_value
    from dict
    where country = par_country;

<snip>
```